# Traduire embrace

Tags: traduction, anglais

> What cannot be eschewed must be embraced - [Shakespeare](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Merry_Wives_of_Windsor#SCENE_5.__Another_part_of_the_Park)
>
> Ce qui ne peut être évité, il faut l’embrasser - [traduit par PPDA](http://www.lemonde.fr/actualite-medias/article/2008/07/10/ppda-ce-qui-ne-peut-etre-evite-il-faut-l-embrasser_1072368_3236.html)

Pardon ? Ô temps, ne suspends pas ton vol, viens dans mes bras !

Le sens d'*embrace* qui m'intéresse ici est le 3e listé par [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embrace) :

> 3.a. to take up especially readily or gladly - *embrace a cause*
> 3.b. to **welcome**, avail oneself of - *embraced the opportunity to study further*

[Mon petit dictionnaire](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/embrace) me dit qu'*embrasser* se traduit ici par ***accepter*** (déjà plus compréhensible, et la traduction de *welcome*), et qu'une autre bonne traduction est ***adopter***.

Mais tout de même, aucun de ces termes ne rend réellement justice à *embrace*, et en particulier *adopter*

- est plus actif qu'*embrace* (qui s'applique plutôt à des choses qu'on subit/accepte passivement),
- peut-être fait *à contrecœur*, ce qui est incompatible avec *embrace*.

Et à *accepter* il manque la partie qui désire (*readily*, *gladly*) que la chose arrive.

Alors, comment pourrait-on traduire l'idée exacte, avec plus de mots ? *Adopter volontairement* ? Quelque chose à base de *faire sienne une idée*, peut-être ?

Comment: Pourquoi pas _embrasser_? Ce mot semble tout à fait adéquat pour traduire _embrace_. Sinon, _accepter_ serait mon deuxième choix.

Comment: Parce qu'aucun des sens listés à http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/embrasser/28656 ne couvre l'emploi d'"embrace" utilisé dans la phrase exemple (= accepter sans répugnance que quelque chose arrive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ce qui ne peut être évité, il faut s'en saisir.
>   Ce qui ne peut être évité, il faut le tourner à son avantage.
>  Ce qui ne peut
>   être évité, il faut l'accueillir à bras ouverts.
>  Ce qui ne peut être évité, il faut s'en prévaloir.
>  Contre mauvaise fortune, il faut faire bon cœur.

Le premier exemple dans le sens de l'*opportunité* inspiré d'une suggestion chez [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/embrace/578173). Le second s'appuyant sur la définition de *saisir [au bond](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bond/10122/locution?q=au%20bond#168997)* lors d'une discussion qu'on *tourne (aussitôt) à son avantage* (Larousse). Le troisième dans le sens d'*avec joie, cordialité* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bras)). Le quatrième [*se prévaloir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A9valoir) pronominal dans le sens de *tirer parti ou avantage de qqc*. Le cinquième, une légère transformation conjuguée de la locution *faire contre (mauvaise) [fortune](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fortune) bon cœur*, dans le sens de *ne pas se laisser décourager par l'adversité* (TLFi), peut-être aussi utile.

Comment: I especially like the second one. I was thinking about "l'accueillir" by itself since I think it defaults to meaning a favorable reception when there's no mention of "how," but using it with "à bras ouverts" is great on several levels, imo.

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks, I think the first one reminds me of _Dead poet society_, something. I'm trying to unwrap the English verb into a verb and a complement in French, in a way that's somewhat reminiscent of its etymology I guess. Cheers!

Comment: ***Accueillir à bras ouverts*** earns the checkmark. +1 for the apt dead poet society reference, +1 for "*contre mauvaise fortune, faire bon coeur*" even though it's a bit convoluted. Go on, keep posting and take all my rep.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Merci, c'est apprécié ! Une belle fin de journée !

Answer (score 1):

> Ce qui ne peut être évité, il faut le **choisir**.

*Choisir* fait partie, avec *approuver, embrasser, suivre*, des synonymes donnés par le petit Robert.

*Adopter* irait très bien aussi, quand ce verbe ne concerne pas la famille :

> ***Adopter*** une décision  à la majorité en Assemblée Générale n'est pas acceptée souvent de bon cœur par la minorité de cette même assemblée.

Comment: J’aime bien «adopter», surtout [sens 2 de ce lien](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/adopter/). Sens 2 parle de votre «choisir» et de la notion (importante, d’après moi) de «faire sienne» dont l’OP parle dans la dernière phrase de sa question. Moi, je vois même une petite connexion pertinente avec le sens 1 d’«adopter» (concernant la famille) en passant par la notion de «faire sien un/l’enfant».

Comment: @PapaPoule ... pas vraiment d'accord sur votre dernière remarque : aussi bien dans le 3.a que dans le 3.b l'OP se réfère à une abstraction, une idée, un concept que l'on peut abandonner par la suite sans créer de drame, pas une réalité vivante que l'on prend en charge pour faire avec elle un bon bout de chemin.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several suggestions.

> *Ce qui ne peut être évité, il faut y adhérer.*
>
> *Ce qui ne peut être évité, il faut s'y résigner.*
>
> *Il faut bien accepter ce qu'on ne peut éviter.*

The latter is used in at least the eighteen and nineteen centuries translations of "The Merry Wives of Windsor", *Les Joyeuses Commères de Windsor*.

Comment: I like the latter

Comment: En imitant 'Il faut bien accepter ce qu'on ne peut éviter', ne pourrait-on pas dire aussi: Il faut faire sien ce qu'on ne peut éviter?

Comment: @AnnieCHABOT Oui, peut-être. « Faire sien » est littéraire et vieilli, ce qui est adapté au contexte. En revanche, il signifie plutôt «s'approprier quelque chose», ce qui n'est pas forcément adapté au contexte du texte de Shakespeare où il est question d'un mariage imposé ou de celui de PPDA où il s'agit d'un «divorce» imposé.

Answer (score 0):

Il me semble que tu sois à la recherche d'un terme français pour rendre le sens figuré d'*embrace* que l'OED définit ainsi :

> *To entwine, encircle, surround; to clasp, enclose*.

Les premiers termes qui me viennent à l'esprit sont  « inclure » et « englober ».

> *The Town of Greenburgh, which embraces several villages in central Westchester County*... ([source](http://www.nytimes.com/1988/01/15/nyregion/town-accepts-plan-to-shelter-the-homeless.html))
>
> La ville de Greenburg qui inclue plusieurs villages....

Dans d'autres cas on pourrait traduire par « s'étendre », comme dans cette phrase prise dans la définition de *embrace*  dans le [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embrace):

> *Charity embraces all acts that contribute to human welfare*
>
> La charité s'étend à tous les actes qui contribuent au bien être de l'humanité.

ou quand le terme est employé pour parler d'une vue (au sens de paysage) dans les guides touristiques par exemple :

*The view embraces the whole Amalfi Coast* ([source](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g580201-d678798-i45648583-Sentiero_degli_dei_Path_of_the_Gods-Agerola_Province_of_Naples_Campania.html))

« englober » conviendrait bien aussi dans ce cas :

> La vue englobe toute la côte / s'étend à ...

Dans ce dernier exemple, « embrasser » est souvent employé en français dans les guides touristiques. Il faudrait faire une recherche plus poussée pour savoir si c'est au départ un anglicisme (même si *embrace* a été au départ importé du français vers l'anglais) ou si le fait que dans cet occurrence le français accorde un sens  affectif.

Ceci dit on emploie « embrasser » est aussi employé en français au sens d'« inclure » /« comprendre », mais bien moins souvent que *embrace* en anglais me semble-t-il.

Comment: Merriam-Webster, excellente idée. Par contre, c'est le sens 3 qui me semble s'appliquer dans cette phrase : ce qu'on ne peut éviter, il faut accepter que ça arrive, sans répugnance / résistance, presque avec velléité.

Answer (score 0):

*Embrasser* paraît adéquat pour la phrase de l'OP, nonobstant le Larousse, qui paraît incomplet dans ce cas. [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/embrasser) semble plus complet et donne les sens et exemples suivants (entre autres):

- Prendre à cœur quelque chose, le prendre à son compte, s'en charger.

  > Sa conscience [de Bénédict] **embrassait** cette tâche [l'éducation de Valentin] avec ardeur (Sand, Valentine,1832, p. 242):
- S'attacher par libre choix à quelque chose, y adhérer, l'adopter et s'y consacrer.

  > Je me sondais, cherchant un état que je pusse **embrasser** sans trop de dégoût, quand feu l'Empereur m'en trouva un; il me dit soldat de par la maladresse de sa politique. Huysmans, Les Soirées de Médan,Sac au dos, 1880, p. 110

Pour *The Town of Greenburgh, which embraces several villages in central Westchester County*, on trouve dans CNRTL:

- Contenir dans son étendue, s'étendre sur l'espace de.

  > La concession embrasse deux mille kilomètres carrés (Reybaud, J. Paturot,1842, p. 31)

Pour *The view embraces the whole Amalfi Coast*, on trouve:

- Embrasser qqc. du/d'un regard, de l'œil; embrasser tout d'un coup d'œil; regard qui embrasse l'horizon, toute l'étendue de qqc; œil qui embrasse d'un coup une surface, un vaste horizon.

  > Pied-d'Alouette fit un geste vague, embrassant un quart de l'horizon (France, Mannequin,1897, p. 69).

Comment: Bon, d'accord, les "deux premiers" choix sont valables. Ce que le texte ne dit pas, c'est que CNRTL précise que ce sens est ***Vieux***, et ***rare***, et le "deuxième sens" mentionné est le a. du "premier sens" qui est 1. Par ailleurs, 1.b et 1.c ne correspondent pas. La deuxième moitié de la réponse est hors-sujet à mon avis, mais pour que vous soyez deux à le mentionner, j'ai mal dû tourner ma question.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks - d'une certaine façon, je ne comprends pas bien la question. PPDA utilise _embrasser_ en 2008, avec un sens proche de celui que vous recherchez, non? En tout cas, les autres réponses commencent souvent de la même façon que la citation de PPDA. Simplement _embrasser_ ne me semble pas faux du tout pour les sens 3.a et 3.b du Merriam-Webster.

Comment: Pour étayer le cas, [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=embrasser+une+cause%2C+embrasser+la+cause&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cembrasser%20une%20cause%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembrasser%20la%20cause%3B%2Cc0) donne par exemple des exemples pour _embrasser une cause_ et _embrasser la cause_ aussi récents que 2000. _Embrasser l'occasion_ se trouve aussi avec google ngrams, quoique plus rare.

Comment: C'est que la question n'est pas "est-il acceptable de traduire comme PPDA ?", mais bien plutôt "je trouve que PPDA utilise des tournures saugrenues, quelles serait la meilleure façon de le dire ?" ;-p - ... "et s'il y avait une nuance ou une autre à ce qu'on voudrait dire avec *embrace*, quelles seraient les autres options ?" La [réponse acceptée](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/24939/1514) est magnifique - *embrasser, adopter, accepter*, merci, mais j'y ai déjà pensé, et ne les trouve pas satisfaisants, c'est dit dans la question. No offense meant.

Comment: La tournure de PPDA ici est-elle saugrenue?

Comment: C'est ce que j'affirme. (Après recherches, plus précisément *vieillie* et *rare*, d'après CNRTL.)

Comment: Je suggérerais les recherches suivantes dans Google: _embrasser l'adversité_, _embrasser l'incertitude_, _embrasser l'opportunité_. Ces tournures sont aisément compréhensibles et ne sont pas du tout choquantes à mon avis.